# ¿Cómo enviar ArrayList de un Activity a un Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de enviar un `Arraylist` de objetos a un `Fragment` ,pero no logro enviarlo, el código que uso es el siguiente:

En el `Activity`:

```
    Fragment fragment = null;
    //creamos un bundle
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("flistaSede",sedesList);
    fragment = new FixturesTabs();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

En el `Fragment` debería recibir,pero no recibe nada,y me imprime una lista vacía:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
            final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                a=  bundle.getParcelableArrayList("flistaSede");
            }
```

Comment: Parece que estás pasando objetos `sedesList` que no se ve en el código de qué tipo son, el `ArrayList a=new ArrayList();` debería ser un arraylist de ese tipo de objetos. Luego, no sé qué hace este método en la recepción de los datos: `getParcelableArrayList` parece que intentarías usar algo como `getParceableArrayList`, y que hay un error de ortografía... ¿o es que tienes un método llamado así en tu modelo? No veo mucha coherencia en tu código, si serializaste con `putSerializable`, ¿por que no usas `getSerializable("flistaSede")` al recuperar el array?

Comment: como alternativa a Parcelable tienes Gson, te dejo un SO donde se ve más o menos su utilidad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761438/how-to-pass-gson-serialised-object-to-intent-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres pasar un `ArrayList` de un `Activity` a un `fragment`, debes usar `implements Parceable` en el modelo que usas para llenar i/o trabajar tu `ArrayList`, para lograrlo, acá un ejemplo:

```
public class ObjectName implements Parcelable {

    public ObjectName(Parcel in) {
        super();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ObjectName> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ObjectName>() {
        public ObjectName createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ObjectName(in);
        }
        public ObjectName[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ObjectName[size];
        }
    };

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Value1 = in.readInt();
        Value2 = in.readInt();
        Value3 = in.readInt();
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(Value1);
        dest.writeInt(Value2);
        dest.writeInt(Value3);
    }
}
```

Ya teniendo algo así, lo que quedaría es enviarlo de esta manera:

```
ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist = new Arraylist<ObjectName>();  
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("flistaSede", arraylist);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Y recibirlo de esta:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
ArrayList<ObjectName> arraylist  = extras.getParcelableArrayList("flistaSede");
```

Para realizar ese proceso mas sencillo te puedo recomendar que implementes la siguiente librería, podría decirse que es el camino fácil para lograr lo que quieres hacer con el camino difícil:

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
```

Aca la [documentación](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) de la misma.

Es una biblioteca de generación de código, que genera el código fuente de `Android Parcelable` repetitivo.

La implementas de la siguiente manera:

En tu modelo que básicamente debería ser solo esto:

```
public class Modulo {
    private String nombre;
    private String estado;

    public Modulo(String nombre, String estado) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
```

Basta con agregar la notación `@Parcel` y crear un constructor vacío, el cual esta biblioteca utilizará para realizar el proceso de `parcelable`.

Quedaría similar a esto:

```
    @Parcel
    public class Modulo {
            private String nombre;
            private String estado;

            public Modulo(String nombre, String estado) {
                this.nombre = nombre;
                this.estado = estado;
            }

            public Modulo() {
                //Constructor vacío
            }

            public String getNombre() {
                return nombre;
            }

            public void setNombre(String nombre) {
                this.nombre = nombre;
            }

            public String getEstado() {
                return estado;
            }

            public void setEstado(String estado) {
                this.estado = estado;
            }
```

Ahora para pasar valores solo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Creas un Bundle

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

// usas el metodo putParcelable para agregar el valor dentro del bundle con su respectiva key
// guardas el parcelable que quieres enviar

bundle.putParcelable("INFORMACION", Parcels.wrap(Array));
```

Luego solo queda recibir el mismo donde deseas recibirlo, así:

```
Ejemplo ejemplo = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("example")); // Desde activity

Ejemplo ejemplo = Parcels.unrap(getArguments().getParcelableExtra("example")); // Desde Fragment
```

Comment: Correcto, yo añadiría como extra la ayuda de android-studio al completar el parcelable es decir encima alt+intro y así se genera todo el código

Comment: Exacto @Webserveis, gracias por añadir ese detalle :)

Comment: Hola @DavidVillegas , y donde irian mis variables, private String sede_id,  private String sede_nombre ? y de que forma.,los cuales son atributos del objeto

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una manera mas practica,con serializable
 esto va en el Activity:

```
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("flistaSede", sedesList);
                fragment = new FixturesTabs();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                                .commit();
```

Y lo recibimos en el Fragment de esta manera:

```
ArrayList<Sede> sedeList = new ArrayList<Sede>();
sedeList = (ArrayList<Sede>) getArguments().getSerializable("flistaSede");
```